# View not re-rendering after onPress

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to change the backgroundColor of a React Native Card component when onPress event is triggered. Although I'm seeing the change of the state on componentDidUpdate, I'm not visualising it.

I'm changing the value of the itemsPressed array when the onPress event is triggered. If the pressed item id is already in the array it removes it else it adds it into the array.

```
export default class Popular extends Component {

 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.togglePressed = this.togglePressed.bind(this);

    this.state = {
     categories: [],
     itemsPressed: []
   }
 }

 togglePressed = item => {
    const id = item.id;
    this.setState(({ itemsPressed }) => ({
      itemsPressed: this.isItemPressed(item)                       
      ? itemsPressed.filter(a => a != id)                            
      : [...itemsPressed, id],
    }))
 };

 isItemPressed = item => {
  const id = item.id;
  return this.state.itemsPressed.includes(id);
 };

 componentDidMount() {
   this.setState({
     categories:this.props.categories,
   });
 }

 componentDidUpdate(){
  console.log(this.state.itemsPressed);
 }

 renderTabItem = ({ item,index }) => (
  <TouchableOpacity
   style={styles.category}
   key={index}
   onPress={() => this.togglePressed(item)}
  >
   <Card center 
    style={[styles.card,{backgroundColor: 
          this.isItemPressed(item) 
          ? item.color 
          : 'gray' 
     }]}>
     <Image source={item.icon} style={styles.categoryIcon}/>
   </Card>
   <Text size={12} center style={styles.categoryName} 
     medium color='black'
    >
    {item.name.toLowerCase()}
   </Text>
 </TouchableOpacity>
 );

renderTab(){
  const {categories} = this.state;
  return (
    <FlatList
    horizontal = {true}
    pagingEnabled = {true}
    scrollEnabled = {true}
    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
    scrollEventThrottle={16}
    snapToAlignment='center'
    data={categories}
    keyExtractor={(item) => `${item.id}`}
    renderItem={this.renderTabItem}
   />
 )
}
  render() {
    return (
       <ScrollView>
        {this.renderTab()}
       </ScrollView>
   );
  }
 }
```

I expected a visual change but I couldn't re render the renderTab().

Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at the [extraData](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#extradata) prop. Does adding `extraData={categories}` fix your problem?

Comment: wow thank you so much ! I assigned a boolean value to the extraData prop then changed it states when onPress was triggered.

Answer (score 1):

Your `FlatList` has the property `category` as data source, so it only re-renders the cells if it detects a change in the `category` property. Your code however is only changing `itemsPressed`, so no cell is re-rendered.

You can tell the `FlatList` to listen for changes `state.itemsPressed` by specifying it in the extraData property:

```
extraData={this.state.itemsPressed}
```